# build wait()/notify() mechanism only with synchronized blocks

Tags: java, concurrency, wait, synchronized, notify

It is possible to build wait/notify mechanism only with syncronized blocks in Java? It means to create this mechanism with out wait()/notify() methods but using syncronized blocks, static fields, volatile modificator.

Comment: Why would you want to do this!

Comment: Sport interest/interview question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, but since you couldn't wait you would be forced to busy-loop:

```
 public class Signal {

     private boolean signal;

     public void waitForSignal() {
          while (true)
               sychronized (this) {
                    if (signal) {
                        signal = false;
                        break;   
                    }
               }
           }
     }

     public synchronized void notifyWithSignal() {
          signal = true;
     }
}
```

Crude but basically that whats behind wait/notify. Only its not looping in wait but use the OS to give the CPU to another thread until signal becomes true.

It can be done just the same by declaring "signal" as volatile and removing the synchronized blocks. Or use AtomicBoolean for signal.